# How to add Store Language in my custom header part

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I have integrated html theme in Magento and now I have to add store language in my custom header part. 
How can I do this ?
Can any one help me ?

Comment: You can use `echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ` to get language switcher in your **header.phtml**

Comment: yes i am already write this code in my form

Comment: Can you add your form file code to the question with your layout xml file code to look for any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly Put code in .phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch')->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

> OR

Add code in your custom layout (.xml) file or local.xml file

```
<default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="page/switch" name="custom_store_language" as="custom_store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Add call using phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_store_language'); ?>
```